# Can't read from datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Creating the entity and setting the property

```
package pack.exp;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class IkaiLanServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws...
{
    Entity alice = new Entity("Person", "Alice");
    alice.setProperty("gender", "female");
    alice.setProperty("age", 20);

    Key bobKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Person", "Bob");
    Entity bob = new Entity(bobKey);
    bob.setProperty("gender", "male");
    bob.setProperty("age", "23");

    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    datastore.put(alice);
    datastore.put(bob);


    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Bye Bye");
}
}
```

In the same package creating another servlet

```
package pack.exp;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;

public class Read extends HttpServlet
{

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws... 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.doGet(req, resp);

    Key bobKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Person", "Bob");
    Key aliceKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Person", "Alice");

    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Entity alice, bob;

    try {
        alice = datastore.get(aliceKey);
        bob = datastore.get(bobKey);

        Long aliceAge = (Long) alice.getProperty("age");
        Long bobAge = (Long) bob.getProperty("age");
        System.out.println("Alice’s age: " + aliceAge);
        System.out.println("Bob’s age: " + bobAge);
    } 

    catch (EntityNotFoundException e) 
    {
        // Alice or Bob doesn't exist!
    }
}
}
```

When I am deploying the app the output is "Bye Bye". Why it is not reading the entity. 
Please help me i am new to google app engine datastore..

Comment: Remco can you help me bro.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to whatever URL you have mapped to `IkaiLanServlet`, it will respond with "Bye Bye" because you called `resp.getWriter().println("Bye Bye")`. To read the entity, change

```
System.out.println("Alice’s age: " + aliceAge);
System.out.println("Bob’s age: " + bobAge);
```

to

```
resp.setContentType("text/plain");
resp.getWriter().println("Alice’s age: " + aliceAge);
resp.getWriter().println("Bob’s age: " + bobAge);
```

According to the docs (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_Logging):

> Everything the servlet writes to the standard output stream (System.out) and standard error stream (System.err) is captured by App Engine and recorded in the application logs. Lines written to the standard output stream are logged at the "INFO" level, and lines written to the standard error stream are logged at the "WARNING" level.

To see the output in your browser, you must use `resp`.

Also, be sure that you visit the URL's for `IkaiLanServlet` and then `Read`, in that order, to ensure the entities are in the datastore.